# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to call a function (findNextOper() ) using async/await and when I call it i get this error:

```
(node:2748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function
```

I have tried adding semicolons in different position but it didn't worked. I have no idea on how to fix it.

```
//This is where I call the function

function regFasiFineLav(pool,oper){
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject,) => {
        ...
        let nextOper = await findNextOper(pool,op);
        ...
        resolve();
 })();
};

//This is the function precedeing the one that trigger the error(findNextOper).
//I pasted because maybe it is related in some way

function StringToTime(stringTime){
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        stringTime = stringTime.split(":");
        resolve(parseInt(stringTime[0])*3600 + parseInt(stringTime[1])*60 + parseInt(stringTime));
    })();
};

//This is the function causing the error
function findNextOper(pool,op){
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        let sql_query = "SELECT TOP 1 oper_num FROM jobroute WHERE job = '" + op.job + "' AND suffix = " + op.suffix + " AND oper_num > " + op.oper_num + " ORDER BY oper_num ASC";
        let result = (await pool.request().query(sql_query)).recordset;
        if(result.length === 0){
            resolve(0);
        }else{
            resolve(result[result.length-1]);
        }
    })();
};
```

I want to execute all these function in sequence since this task cannot be done async

Comment: why do you combine promise creation and async functions? It's redundant.

Comment: What is the expected result of `parseInt(stringTime)`?

Comment: Also, the `StringToTime` isn't even doing anything async so why wrap it in 2 promises?

Comment: Yeah I know it's redundant, I just forgot to remove them.
Honestly, I don't remember what the purpose of parseInt is, I have the source code in office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `()` following `Promise` constructor. Remove `()` following invocation of the constructor. Chain `.catch()` to `Promise`s to avoid `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem! I'm not very handy with promises